# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined (D3.JS)

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, html5-canvas

This error popped up when i tried to retrieve **JSON data** and make it a **line graph.**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Here's my **JS** :

```
d3.json("../js/sample2.json", function(data) {
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

    var i = 0;
    var group = canvas.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100,100");


    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d, i) {
                console.log("x" + d[0].position[i]);
                return d[0].position[i];
            })
            .y(function(d, i) {
                console.log("y" + d[1].position[i]);
                return d[1].position[i];
            });

    group.selectAll("path")
            .data([data]).enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 5);
});
```

Here's my JSON :

```
[{"name": "x", "position":[40,60,80,100] },
 {"name": "y", "position":[70,190,220,160]}
]
```

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAG2r/23/)

Can someone help me out with this?

I want the line to be displayed from the data that is retrieved from the **JSON file.**

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
d3.json("../js/sample2.json", function(data) {

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);
    console.log(data);

    var group = canvas.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(100,100");


    var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d, i) {
//                console.log(data[0].position[i]);
                return data[0].position[i];
            })
            .y(function(d, i) {
//                console.log(data[1].position[i]);
                return data[1].position[i];
            });


    group.selectAll("path")
            .data([data]).enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", line(data[0].position))
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 5);
});
```

> ```
> Had to provide .attr("d", line(data[0].position))
> ```